# 「大画面向けの新しい Play ストアの紹介」の対応方法と効果

Tags: google-play, google-play-service, google-play-console

Android 開発者ブログ「大画面向けの新しい Play ストアの紹介（※）について教えてください。
（※） https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/07/introducing-new-play-store-for-large-screens.html

**■「大画面アプリの品質ガイドライン」（※）のTier1,2,3**
①Tier1,2,3の3段階すべてに対応しないと「検索とアプリとゲームのホームで上位にランク」されないでしょうか。
②Tier3より、Tier2,1に対応したほうが検索とアプリとゲームのホームでより上位にランクされることはありますでしょうか。
当社アプリはTier3に対応済みです。Tier1,2に対応するとより上位になるか把握したいです。
（※） https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/large-screen-app-quality?hl=ja

**■「検索とアプリとゲームのホームで上位にランクされるようになります」**
③検索で上位にランクされるとはどういうことでしょうか。
例えばXというヘルスケアアプリを公開してる場合、『ヘルスケア』で検索したユーザによりXが上位表示されるということでしょうか。
④具体的にどれほど上位表示されますでしょうか（約5-10アプリ等）。②のTier1,2,3ごとに効果が変わる場合、Tier1,2,3でそれぞれご教示ください。

ご知見をおかしください。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。